# How to update data and render new components with API call after change of route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm still new to React so I have this project which has a drawer component with several routes (Dashboard, Chart, and User Settings). Under the Dashboard component (which also consists of the Navbar and Drawer component), I have a TablePage, ChartPage and SettingsPage components which will be rendered based from the route.

When I log in, it will render the table component in the `/dashboard` which gets the data from an API. If I click `Chart` from the drawer, it will reroute to `/chart`.

Currently it will call an API which will get the information when the dashboard component is loaded (`/dashboard`) and it will pass all necessary data (props) to the child component in ChartPage and SettingsPage. The problem is, if the database is updated, I will need to refresh the page in order to get the updated data. What I want to do, is whenever the user clicks on the button from the drawer, it will call the API to get the updated value.

In order to that, I'm using the useContext hooks which will pass the `readData` function to the TablePage component. How do I render it once if there is no information is updated and will render the component if there is an updated information from the database? Apparently it says that the readData is not a function even though I retrieve it from the useContext method in `TablePage.js`.

Dashboard.js

```
import clsx from "clsx";
import Drawer from "@material-ui/core/Drawer";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import ChevronLeftIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft";
import DrawerHeader from "./DrawerHeader";
import DrawerContent from "./DrawerContent";
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect, Fragment } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
// import RefreshIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Refresh";
// import Badge from "@material-ui/core/Badge";
// import NotificationsIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Notifications";
import ToggleMenu from "./ToggleMenu";
import Loader from "./Loader";
import axios from "axios";
import AuthApi from "../utils/createContext";
import moment from "moment";
import PageRoute from "./PageRoute";
import DataApi from "../utils/createContext";

const m = moment();
const today = m.format("LL");

// function refresh() {
//   setTimeout(function () {
//     window.location.reload();
//   }, 100);
// }

const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
  },
  listContainer: {
    display: "flex",
  },
  toolbar: {
    paddingRight: 24, // keep right padding when drawer closed
  },
  toolbarIcon: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    padding: "0 8px",
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
  },
  appBar: {
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["width", "margin"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
  },
  appBarShift: {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["width", "margin"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: 36,
  },
  menuButtonHidden: {
    display: "none",
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    position: "relative",
    whiteSpace: "nowrap",
    width: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  drawerPaperClose: {
    overflowX: "hidden",
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    width: theme.spacing(7),
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      width: theme.spacing(9),
    },
  },
  appBarSpacer: theme.mixins.toolbar,
  // content: {
  //   flexGrow: 1,
  //   height: "100vh",
  //   overflow: "auto",
  // },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    display: "flex",
    overflow: "auto",
    flexDirection: "column",
  },
  fixedHeight: {
    height: 240,
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    // marginLeft: "-70px",
  },
  contentShift: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
    marginLeft: 0,
  },
}));

export default function Dashboard2() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const { value } = useContext(AuthApi);

  //get user and customer api
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});
  const [customerData, setCustomerData] = useState([]);
  const [customerCount, setCustomerCount] = useState();
  const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);

  const readData = async () => {
    const fetchUserInfo = await axios.post(`/auth/getemail/${value}`);

    console.log(fetchUserInfo);
    // console.log(result.data.user[0]._id);
    const { data } = fetchUserInfo;
    const { user } = data;

    let newUserData = {};

    user.forEach((cData) => {
      newUserData = {
        joindate: cData.joindate,
        email: cData.email,
        adminId: cData.adminId,
        _id: cData._id,
      };
    });

    // console.log(newUserData);
    setUserData(newUserData);

    const fetchCustomerInfo = await axios.post(
      `/customerinfo/getcustomer/${fetchUserInfo.data.user[0].adminId}`
    );

    // console.log(fetchCustomerInfo);

    const cust = fetchCustomerInfo.data;

    // console.log(cust.customer_info);
    // console.log(cust.count);
    setCustomerData(cust.customer_info);
    setCustomerCount(cust.count);
    setIsFetching(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    readData();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  // const username = value.slice(0, value.search("@"));

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {isFetching ? (
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <CssBaseline />
          <AppBar
            position="absolute"
            className={clsx(classes.appBar, open && classes.appBarShift)}
          >
            <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
              <IconButton
                edge="start"
                color="inherit"
                aria-label="open drawer"
                onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
                className={clsx(
                  classes.menuButton,
                  open && classes.menuButtonHidden
                )}
              >
                <MenuIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <Typography
                component="h1"
                variant="h6"
                color="inherit"
                noWrap
                className={classes.title}
              >
                Dashboard
              </Typography>

              {/* <IconButton color="inherit" onClick={refresh}>
                <RefreshIcon />
              </IconButton> */}
              {/* <IconButton color="inherit">
                <Badge badgeContent={4} color="secondary">
                  <NotificationsIcon />
                </Badge>
              </IconButton> */}
              <ToggleMenu />
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>

            <Drawer
              variant="persistent" //persistent,permanent,temporary
              anchor="left"
              classes={{
                paper: clsx(
                  classes.drawerPaper,
                  !open && classes.drawerPaperClose
                ),
              }}
              open={open}
            >
              <div className={classes.toolbarIcon}>
                <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
                  <ChevronLeftIcon />
                </IconButton>
              </div>

              <DrawerHeader
                email={userData.email}
                joindate={moment(userData.joindate).format("LL")}
                id={userData._id}
              />
              <DrawerContent />
            </Drawer>
          <DataApi.Provider
            value={{
              customerData,
              customerCount,
              userData,
              isFetching,
              readData,
            }}
          >
          <main
            className={clsx(classes.content, {
              [classes.contentShift]: open,
            })}
          >
            <div className={classes.appBarSpacer} />
            <PageRoute
              customerdata={customerData}
              userdata={userData}
              customercount={customerCount}
              momentdate={today}
            />
          </main>
         </DataApi.Provider>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <Loader type={"Bars"} color={"#9370DB"} />
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

TablePage.js

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, Fragment } from "react";
import MaterialTable from "material-table";
import { Container, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import DataApi from "../utils/createContext";
import Loader from "./Loader";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  container: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(4),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(4),
  },
}));

export default function TablePage({ customerdata }) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const { readData, isFetching } = useContext(DataApi);

  useEffect(() => {
    readData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {isFetching ? (
        <div>
          <Container maxWidth="lg" className={classes.container}>
            <Grid>
              <MaterialTable
                columns={[
                  { title: "Customer Name", field: "fullname" },
                  { title: "Phone No.", field: "phone", type: "string" },
                  { title: "Address", field: "address" },
                  { title: "Date", field: "updated", type: "date" }, //Data type: 'boolean', 'numeric', 'date', 'datetime', 'time', 'currency'
                  { title: "Time", field: "updated", type: "time" },
                ]}
                data={customerdata}
                title="Check-In Information"
                options={{
                  exportButton: true,
                  filtering: true,
                }}
              />
            </Grid>
          </Container>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <Loader type={"Bars"} color={"#9370DB"} />
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

UPDATED: DataApi.Provider location is changed to wrap only the Routes component and the readData dependencies on the useEffect for Table.js has been removed

Comment: In table page, did you try if (readData) readData(); in the useeffect, because it might be the case that for the very first time it is not yet defined for some reason. And as soon as it gets defined it will be available. Also in the dashboard, use useCallback properly for defining readData to avoid other issues.

Comment: I rewrapped the DataApi.Provider to include the Routes component as the TablePage,ChartPage are inside that component. However, when I do this, the Loader component kept on loading (isFetching is false )as if the no API is being called on the Dashboard.js

Comment: pleas eudpate question with latest code if so

Comment: I have updated the code. I managed to fix the problem and it updates the readData when I clicked on the button. Can you tell me more on the usage of the useCallback for defining readData? What kind of issues will happen?

Comment: Official docs describe useCallback pretty good, please refer there. And post your answer to this question, or close the question. Thanks.